# How to have a jersey web service class implement interface and be transactional

Tags: java, jersey, spring-transactions

I would like to use Jersey and Spring to write a java class that is both a web service server-side class and also transactional with spring-tx (so that each web service request either completely finishes its work in the db or completely rolls back its work in the db).

But, when I do that like so...

```
package com.test.rest

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component 
@Transactional
public class TestRestService implements TestRestServiceInterface {
    ...
}
```

the TestRestService class is not registered as a web service class by Spring.

I am using `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.rest"/>` in my spring config file to register the web service classes in the com.test.rest package (package name changed for the example).

If I either remove @Transactional or have TestRestService not implement an interface the class is registered by Spring as a web service class and the code works.

Is there a way for me to have both?

I am currently using sprint-tx, spring-jersey and spring-context 3.0.7 and jersey 1.0.3.1

Comment: What if you remove that interface and use CGLIB proxies? Add CGLIB and enable class based proxies in Spring.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, but we would like to keep the interface if possible and without it even the default JDK dynamic proxies work fine.  Ideally, we would like to have the interface and have the class be transactional.

Comment: Correction, I found out from the documentation and Tomasz' own article on spring aop pitfalls that JDK proxies don't work work without interfaces.  I wonder if I can use a CGLIB proxy with an interface.  I'm going to try that.

Comment: I changed `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.test"/>` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.rest" scoped-proxy="targetClass"/>` and the problem persisted.  I guess it's just not meant to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at this a lot I have come to the conclusion that it just will not work (without AspectJ perhaps).

I believe it won't work because of this code in jersey-server-1.0.3.1:com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig.java

```
438  /**
439   * Determine if a class is a root resource class.
440   *
441   * @param c the class.
442   * @return true if the class is a root resource class, otherwise false
443   *         (including if the class is null).
444   */
445  public static boolean isRootResourceClass(Class<?> c) {
446      if (c == null)
447          return false;
448      
449      if (c.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) return true;
450  
451      for (Class i : c.getInterfaces())
452          if (i.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) return true;
453  
454      return false;
455  }
```

For some reason, when we have @Transactional on a class that implements an interface the Proxy class generated by spring-tx (whether CGLIB or JDK Dynamic proxy based) doesn't have the @Path annotation so isRootResourceClass returns false and the class is not registered as a web service class.  I verified this while debugging through the code.

I guess I am just going to have to choose between implementing an interface or making my web service class transactional (unless I go with AspectJ).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

I am having a similar problem, where my jersey based rest service class has @ Transactional annotation on some methods (PUT). But it gives me a null pointer exception (for an @ autowired DAO) when I invoke the service method from a rest service client. If I remove @ Transactional from the method then it doesn't throw null pointer but it also doesn't commit the transaction. I have also tried it with AOP from XML with the same result. It seems like it can't deal with transactional methods. My application is based on Spring 3.1, JPA and Jersey 1.17

Comment: Ok I got it resolved. It works when you separate your transactional service from the jersey resource. Meaning rather than using jersey annotations in your transactional service class, you create a new class, which is exposed as a jersey resource. This new jersey resource can then use the transactional service class(inject via spring) to persist objects.